# Integral of a determinant of Jacobian depends on the boundary values only

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, determinant

Let $B$ be the closed unit ball in $\mathrm{R}^n$ with the 2-norm. Let $\phi : B \to \mathrm{R}^n$ be smooth such that $\det D \phi = 1$ on $\partial B$.

Why is $\int_B \det D \phi = \int_B 1$?

In other words, why does this integral only depend on the values of $\phi$ on $\partial B$?

Can one use polar coordinates (rather than differential geometry) to show this?

**Edit**: a nice explanation using Gauss divergence theorem is [here](http://www.math.toronto.edu/rjerrard/1061/determinants.pdf).